# Output tags jsf expression language

Tags: java, jsf, el

my problem is that I have a  that contains variables that also to be iterated over. 
I have tried to put use nested  and  but they don't work. 
Another attempt at a solution I working on is outputting

```
<ul> <li>Value</li>...</ul>
```

for the inner loop from a method call. The problem is that it generates this:

```
&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Value&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
```

How do I force it to output what I want? Any other suggestion for solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the escape="false" attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow, I overlooked that attribute.